# tmp directory not cleaning while using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tmp

I am using jenkins 1.451 on AIX 7.0 with job carrying out checkout,compile and pushing code to our environment.

Also a Sonar job is configured on jenkins.  Here, Jenkins is not implemented using apache or as RPM.  We have just extracted the war and are using 2-3 jobs to compile and push code.  I know jenkins uses the tmp directory to run the jobs.  I have seen following files in /tmp directory which I guess are left even job has finished.

PFB the names of files which are present in large number

```
1.xbean2456858964200604902.d
2.jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jenkins.war-_jenkins-any-
3.sonar-batch21583185812212985831389617600951909000
4.winstone8285452915548449514.jar
5.fixcrlf1440303164
```

Is it normal to have such files in large number.  How do we clean up these files ???

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Files in /tmp are unlikely to be harmful to delete.  `/tmp` is cleared on reboot on most systems.

You could add another jenkins job with the build triggers set to "build after other projects are built" with a list of all the other projects

Then do a build "execute shell" command such as

```
find /tmp -user jenkins -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Where "jenkins" is the jenkins user name

If the user name is likely to be shared with other processes that also write temp files then you will need to force jenkins to write its temp files to a known, alternative destination by setting java.io.tmpdir

Comment: It can be useful but we are using a generic userID for jenkins and other works.And using your idea may delete those files too which are not generated by jenkins.Am I right ?

Comment: In that case I guess you need to force jenkins to write all its temp files somewhere else apart from /tmp so you can be sure that they are all jenkins temporary files.  Updated answer

Comment: "/tmp is cleared on reboot on most systems." - not really handy for a build server that doesn't reboot, ever.

Comment: @Nyerguds it is possible to use immutable infrastructure and other tactics like that on your build system.  And it's not just clearing /tmp that might make you wish to do this.  For instance, I found that the particular version of jenkins I was using at one place occassionally died after updates.  As this jenkins ran in a VM it was easy to roll it back from a backup to the pre update state